# Ubuntu does not see whole partition after resizing

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, disk-usage

I have a 1TB NVME Samsung SSD which had 2 major partitions (apart from efi).

One 325GB which contained Ubuntu, and one about 600GB which contained Windows.

I decided to stop dual-booting to use only Ubuntu. So I booted on live usb, and using gparted, i removed the 600GB partition, I expanded the 325GB to fill the empty space and I fixed grub.

Everything went well except Ubuntu doesn't see the expanded partition.

fdisk -l returns this

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 96B74F5A-B917-49C4-A63F-6225ACC52262

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3 206848 1953490943 1953284096 931.4G Linux filesystem
```

df -h returns this

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3           325G  302G  6.1G  99% /
```

Ubuntu tells me that my disk is full

KDE Partition manager clearly sees the whole partition, and the 307GiB used, as shown in following screenshot

[image: KDE Partition Manager showing full partition]

How can I make Ubuntu see the whole expanded partition?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly did you resize the partition? Can you add the entire output from `fdisk -l` (add to your question, please)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally found the missing step.

All that was remaining to do was

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

Now df -h returns this

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3           916G  145G  731G  17% /
```

Hope this helps someone else